# Are vtables generated for all types that implement a trait?

Tags: rust, traits, vtable, trait-objects

If I have a trait `Foo`, and some implementors `Bar`, `Baz`.

```rust
impl Foo for Bar {
}
```

```rust
impl Foo for Baz {
}
```

But say I only use one of them ever as a trait object,

```rust
let bar = Bar {..};
let foo: &dyn Foo = &bar;
```

Then will my binary still have vtable for both?
Does this behaviour change between debug and release builds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's find out. I put this similar code [in the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc55eb3bb682e0da07dbe0ac89005ca5) and ran “Show Assembly”:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn x(&self);
}
impl Foo for u8 {
    fn x(&self) {
        dbg!("xu8");
    }
}
impl Foo for u16 {
    fn x(&self) {
        dbg!("xu16");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo: &dyn Foo = &123_u8;
    foo.x();
    123_u8.x();
    123_u16.x();
}
```

In the (debug mode) assembly output, `main` is:

```
playground::main:
    subq    $24, %rsp
    leaq    .L__unnamed_12(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_2(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_12(%rip), %rdi
    callq   *.L__unnamed_2+24(%rip)
    leaq    .L__unnamed_12(%rip), %rdi
    callq   <u8 as playground::Foo>::x
    leaq    .L__unnamed_13(%rip), %rdi
    callq   <u16 as playground::Foo>::x
    addq    $24, %rsp
    retq
```

We don't need to be able to read every detail of x86 assembly to see that there are three function calls here, the last two of which are the static calls I added for comparison. So, `.L__unnamed_2` probably has something to do with the vtable. What's that?

```
.L__unnamed_2:
    .quad   core::ptr::drop_in_place<u8>
    .asciz  "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"
    .quad   <u8 as playground::Foo>::x
```

Looks like a vtable to me: it's referring to drop glue and to an implementation of `x()`. But there is nothing that does the same for `u16` — the only reference to `<u16 as playground::Foo>::x` is the statically dispatched call in `main`.

Of course, this doesn't rule out that the compiler generated the vtable data, then threw it out before getting to the assembly listing. But if it did, then either that would be a compiler performance bug, or it would be so cheap as to not be worth worrying about.

(Also, as more anecdotal evidence: the Rust compiler is [known to generate multiple vtables for the same type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46139) if they happen to be needed in separate codegen units.)